# Bitdefender Firewall blocking Wifi (trusted network), No DNS probe finished

Tags: wireless-networking, dns

Bitdefender has blocked my wifi network multiple times, and when i load the internet google chrome says DNS probe not finished. The only way i can get on to the internet is to turn off the fire wall and load my wifi then turn it back on, essentially i cant load the internet straight after i turn on my computer. I think BD is changing the wifi to not trusted or public each time i turn off my computer. Is there a simple way to fix this? is this characteristic of BD? I am using windows 7.

I have tried to use the BitDefender forum but it seems to be poorly constructed and quite useless really.

Answer (score 0):

I've been encountering the same issue for 2 weeks now. This fixed it for me:

- In Firewall Settings go to Adapters Tab.
- My NIC is Network Type "Trusted".
- By I have switched Stealth Mode "Off"

This solved it for me. I tested:

I turned Stealth Mode back "On" and could reproduce the DNS Probing error again. Turning Stealth Mode "Off" again, and was able to connect to the internet again.